# NHibernate SELECT N+1 despite using HQL query with eager fetch

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am experiencing a **SELECT N+1** problem with NHibernate. I therefore looked into using HQL (and even Criterias) to solve the problem.

I am getting the same problem with HQL as well. First let me show how the object graph looks like.

- User (Has a collection to UserRoles, i.e. a *one-to-many* relationship.)
- UserRoles (Has a *many-to-one* reference back to User, and also a *many-to-one* to Role).
- Role (Has a *one-to-many* relationship to UserRoles)

The HQL query is as follows:

```
from User u
    left join fetch u.UserRoles
    where u.id = :userID
```

The first query I see being executed is this (some columns have been removed):

```
select user0_.ID                    as ID12_0_,
   userrole1_.ID                   as ID33_1_,
   user0_.VersionNumber         as VersionN2_12_0_,
   user0_.Name             as UserName12_0_
   userrole1_.VersionNumber        as VersionN2_33_1_,
   userrole1_.UserID          as Us11_33_1_,
   userrole1_.RoleID               as RoleID33_1_,
   userrole1_.UserID          as Us11_0__,
   userrole1_.ID                   as ID0__
from   [User] user0_
   left outer join [UserRoles] userrole1_
     on user0_.ID = userrole1_.UserID
     where  user0_.ID = 139
```

Then I see a lot of these queries (the N+1 problem):

```
SELECT ...
FROM   [UserRoles] userrole0_
WHERE  userrole0_.UserID = 64
```

I think the problem is the reference in UserRoles back to User (or even the fact that UserRoles leads to Role, which again leads back to UserRoles, which leads to User again).

I've tried all kinds of variations of the HQL queries and even adding more joins, but I haven't found a solution that gets rid of this problem.

Comment: do you have something like this?

    `from User u
        left join fetch u.UserRoles r
        where u.id = :userID and r.Something = something`?

Comment: Perhaps did you map with not-found="ignore" clause?

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you haven't defined a [fetching strategy](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching) for your associations?